# Domain Name Does Not Exist In The Database DNN

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, dotnetnuke

I have a custom **DotNetNuke** website I am trying to setup on local machine.

I have already setup **SQL 2012** database with **db_owner** credentials and **SQL Authentication**. Tested fine with **SQL Server Management Studio**. I have changed the directories security credentials for respective users.

Similarly changed **PortalAlias** tables' **HTTPAlias** columnn and **PortalSetting** tables' **SettingPortal** column for **DefaultPortalAlias** for website name (Local web server address ).

Also changed connectionstrings in **ConnectioStrings** and **AppSettings** sections.

Now I am getting

> Domain Name Does Not Exist In The Database

error when I try to run my website.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved this using help of my friend. There are some things which must take in considetaion while solving this issue.

1. `HostSettings` : In database table named `HostSettings`, change `AutoAddPortalAlias` to `Y`. Although this change is optional, application will add the domain name into `PortalAlias` table.
2. `PortalAlias` : If you use above `HostSettings` trick, application will automatically add `PortalAlias` but make sure to remove `\` trailing domain name if there's any. Although this looks small change but keeping `\` will create problem running application. Also create two entries with and without `http`. e.g. `http://<domainName>.com` and `<domainName>.com`.
3. `PortalSettings` : Change `DefaultPortalAlias` to your domain name without the trailing `\`.
4. `Hosts` : Create a entry in `C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts` file for your domain name with `IP Address : 127.0.0.1` i.e. `localhost`

This changes are very similat to the question I asked but these small things does matter very much. No need to make any change in connectioString or Databse Connectivity options. This solved my problem completely.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are adding an existing DNN website to your local machine.

To get the domain name to work you can try these solutions. But first undo the changes you did in the database or attach a fresh copy from backup.

Add the original domain name to IIS and modify the `hosts` file on the local machine. Then login and add a development alias. If that works you can remove the original domain name from the hosts file. That way you don't need to change anything in the database directly.

Or

Set the `AutoAddPortalAlias` to `Y` in the `HostSettings` table of the DNN database.

Comment: You are right. I am trying to setup existing site to local machine. Thanks for suggestions. I'll try these and post results here

Comment: Then there is a problem with the database (connection). If you modified the hosts and added the domain name to your local IIS, to DNN there would be no difference between local and production and it should run.

Comment: Well, the database connection is fine. At least I tried with same credentials with SSMS and its working fine. And that is why I am confused here. What can be other possibilities ?

Comment: You have a similar issue in your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40233283/installing-dotnetnuke-database-connection-failing). It would seem your database is not reachable from an IIS website. Write a simple script to test the connection. And check the SQL logs for failed logins.

Answer (score 0):

The message says "The domain does not exist in the database."  So, besides adding a binding for the domain to IIS, you need to add a Portal Alias.  The easiest way to do this is by using the Admin, Site Settings.

Now ... since you presumably can't get to the site, you have two choices.

1. Login to another site on the installation as superuser.  Then you will be able to use Host, Site Settings to edit any of the portals, and that includes adding a portal alias.
2. Using SQL Server Management Studio, you can add a portal alias directly to the PortalAlias table in the DNN database.

Comment: Tried 2nd method already. Not working, mentioned above. And I don't have access to either interface to try 1st method.