# DNN8 and SQL Server 2014 connection issue

Tags: dotnetnuke, sql-server-2014-express, dotnetnuke-8

I have SQL Server 2014 installed as a default instance `MSSQLSERVER`. My computer's name is `DHAVAL-PC`.

So I used to connect SQL Server database engine with `DHAVAL-PC`.

[image]

Coming to DNN 8 Installation, I used to type my server name as `DHAVAL-PC` and the empty database that I have created. But I am getting the following error:

[image]

Even I tried with `MSSQLSERVER`, `DHAVAL-PC/MSSQLSERVER`, `./MSSQLSERVER`, `.`.
None of the server names worked.

Comment: Can you login to your server using **SQL Server Management Studio** with `.` or `DHAVAL-PC` ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing DotNetNuke : Database Connection Failing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40233283/installing-dotnetnuke-database-connection-failing)

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that DNN 8 service is not running with your identity (account). This identity can not login to the database server.

So figure out under which identity does this process/service run and then add this service account to the database, configure access rights too.

... or just create an SQL server account, with username/password and then set security to "User defined".

Answer (score 0):

What identity is your site running under? Assuming you are using IIS look at the identity field of your application pool. If it is an application pool identity make sure you have granted owner permission on the database to that application pool.

To do that, add `IIS APPPOOL\<application_pool_name>` as a user/logon in sql server