# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:6457 - SQL Server Express

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am running IIS and SQL Server Express 2019. No active firewall. I have enabled the TCP/IP.

I have database running. I gave full permission to IIS USER
localhost is just working fine. When I entered the username and password in the login page.

I get an error

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it  127.0.0.1:6457

It worked for the first time then it didn't even though I didn't make any changes. It works on my personal computer and I used the same configuration on the other one.

Here is the what I have in the `web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="XXXXX" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.1.1\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=XXXXXX;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xx;Password=xxxxxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

```
<add key="APIAddress" value="http://localhost:6457/"/>
<add key="WebAddress" value="http://localhost:6913/"/>
```

When I run the project from the VS studio it opens two tabs in Edge;

- `localhost:645` is not working but
- `localhost:6913` is working (welcome page).

I think there is a connection issue is going but I don't know how to fix it.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Try the steps in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40261534/5836671

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full and complete error message - as text, not screen shots. Based on what's posted in the question `127.0.0.1:6457` should have a HTTP service listening on it, not an SQL Server service.